# 404 Error Page at first login to admin panel - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Since a few days I have the weird issue, that when I first login to my magento admin panel, it will show a 404 error page. The header and menu items are all visible but the page content shows 404.
As soon as I click any given link, it will work and also the overview page works normally.

I have tried the common tweaks to resolve it, I couldn't fix the problem yet though.

Comment: Can you post the server errors or more details ?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean exactly? I dont have any logfiles etc. after logging in. anytime I start to login uncached (private tab with browse f.e.) it will show the same 404 page within the admin panel

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.it started after upgrading to 1.9.3.10

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and from the comments there is no comprehension of the sequence. This only happen for the FIRST LOGIN, but is is only the "main page content (<div id="page:main-container">) that has the 404 error, not the entire page. So the header and menu are still accessible. As in the original question once selecting a menu item everything works. That is to say my login page is https://somewesite.com/admin/dashboard/ and the dashboard does not load but generates a "404 page not found", but clicking the dashboard menu button displays the DashBoard.
[image: Login]